# Streamlit with Pyinstaller issue

Tags: pyinstaller, executable, streamlit, transformer-model, large-language-model

my streamlit app uses transformer and also i have no streamli and transformer installed in my global pip. I have my development using virtual env and when i am running pyinstaller created .exe file from my virtual environment, it is working fine, but when i am double clicking or opening the .exe file using powershell or cmd, it is not working.

Clicking .exe from cmd is opening and closing black and white window, i used streamlit and transformers in hidden import, still not working.